# ошибка после установки Owncloud

Tags: owncloud

Не установлен PHP-модуль zip.
Пожалуйста, попростите администратора сервера установить модуль.

Модули PHP были установлены, но они все еще перечислены как недостающие?
Пожалуйста, попросите вашего администратора перезапустить веб-сервер.

Answer (score 0):

Из Джино - 
Действительно, иногда бывает так, что код кэшируется, и чтобы изменения вступили в силу, необходимо перезагружать веб-сервер. Это можно сделать через контрольную панель в разделе «Хостинг / Управление / Настройки веб сервера», нажав на кнопку «Перезагрузить».